# C# Membership.ValidateUser(Username, Password) throwing an exception

Tags: c#

I am trying to validate a user using the Membership.ValidateUser() method. I pass the correct username and password, and the authentical always failed. The Else section of the code is executed. I add a breakpoint, and I notice the following: 'Response.Headers' threw an exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException - This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline'. I check the application pool, and it is set to use **Integrated pipeline.**

The create Membership.CreateUser() works fine.  I am only having issue retrieving users. Below is my web.config file.

I look at the definition, and this is all that is showing 
public static bool ValidateUser(string username, string password) (under the page name [Membership from metadata] .

Answer (score 0):

I did not register the ASP.NET database As a result, it could not find the membership table and other related procedure. I changed directory to *c:\Windows\Microsoft.net\Framework64\V4.0*. Then I ran the *aspnet_regsql.exe*.